# Identify exception origin from exception properties in WPF (C# .Net) app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, error-handling

I am recently assigned a task to extend an existing WPF (C# .Net) application for an error handler. The handler is supposed to display a friendly message with possible easy solution for the user. It is required that I change nearly no code = I can only work in App.xaml.cs code behind. My approach is to try to identify the error from the stack trace and from the properties of the innermost exception. So far, I am using these three identifiers:

```
string identifierMethod= new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex.GetBaseException()).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;  
string identifierObject = ex.GetBaseException().TargetSite.ReflectedType.FullName;
string identifierHResult = ex.GetBaseException().HResult.ToString();
//ex is the uppermost exception coming to App
```

I need to identify the root method and object where the exception originated. Combining these three seems to work for me but I don’t think it is very clean and robust and I fear there could be some exception that will have duplicate combination of these three identifiers. Sometimes the innermost exception’s stack trace is null, sometimes it seems to me the identifiers do not really describe the lowermost method or object constructor which caused the Exception.
I know I could ideally use Exception Data or Source properties assigning some identifiers in try catch block where the Exception originate but I simply cannot. I know similar question were asked but they only gave me what I have now.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: Why not show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Exceptions are rarely useful for the user. Usually with unhandled exceptions you log them and tell them something went wrong, and if pain persists see your doctor (or development to inspect the logs) -- Also the inner most exception might not be the most human readable, or it might. there might not even be a singular hierarchy (aggregate ect)... In short i think you are doing about all you can do

Comment: *"The handler is supposed to display a friendly message with possible easy solution for the user"* - that's a hell of a work for big enough application. The idea of catching exceptions and identifying which message to show is wrong. For unhandled exceptions you need generic "Error occurs, shutting down, please see logs, contact service, etc.". For *friendly* messages you'll need to programm something directly in every place you are handling, e.g. in addition to logging exception display something to the user,where explanation and recommendations are very much tuned to only that place and case.

Comment: If you get the innermost exception. Isn't the stack trace of that the method name and class name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Checked Exceptions** to announce the caller methods about the callees' exceptions. And in caller methods, you can easily handle the exception by their types, identify the exception origin, and have a friendly message.
To add the **Checked Exception** feature into the `C#`, you can use this nugget package: [Portia.Roslyn.CheckedException](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portia.Roslyn.CheckedException/).